# Nested Tree Angular material

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material, nested-lists

I am currently working on a project where users can edit translations based on versions in langauges.

For example: An user want's to change a specific translation in version 1.1 in english language

How do I structure the data for the tree?

I created these interfaces which is how I want to gather the data

```
interface TreeNode {
  treeName: string //Languages
  children?: LanguageNode[];
}
interface LanguageNode {
  languageName: string //en-US
  children?: VersionNode[];
}
interface VersionNode {
  versionName: string //version 1.1
}
```

What is the appropiate treeControl and dataSource for this structure?